# "Element <> could not be scrolled into view" error not responding to usual solutions

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, podcast

I'm using selenium to design a scraper to mass-download podcast episodes from Spreaker.

```
# https://www.spreaker.com/show/alabamas-morning-news-with-jt


for i in range(3):
    print("Click number: {}".format(str(i)))
    see_more = browser.find_element_by_id("show episodes more")
    see_more.click()
    browserPage = bs4(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    allEps.append( allEpisodesOnPage(browserPage) )
```

Since they aren't all on numbered pages (/episodes/page1, /page2), I have to click a button to load more.

But for some reason, my code can't find the button:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KeepTalking__02.py", line 59, in <module>
    see_more.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a id="show_episodes_more" class="btnn btnn_alternative btnn_small" href="#"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Now, "could not be scrolled into view" is a standard error in Selenium, and I was inundated with possible solutions:

1. Scroll the element into view.
2. Wait for the element to become visible:

   ```
   element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
       ex_co.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#show_episodes_more")))
   ```
3. Switch to the frame that it's on.

But for some reason, I'm still getting the exact same error. What could cause this? I took a screenshot and the button was on the page, so I don't understand where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Basically ElementNotInteractableException is occurs when emporary Overlay of other WebElement over the WebElement. To avoid ElementNotInteractableException you can use ActionChains please refer below solution :

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        ex_co.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#show_episodes_more")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

or

```
element= wait(self.browser,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='show_episodes_more']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved